# Can't import module from different directory python

Tags: python, file, path

So below I have is my file structure:

```
/
    api.py       
    app.py       
code/
    data_api/
        weather_data/
            get_data_dir/
                get_data.py
            master_call_dir/
                master_call.py
```

My current problem is that I'm importing `master_call.py` from inside `app.py` I do this with the following code:

```
-- app.py

import sys
sys.path.append('./code/data_api/weather_data/master_call_dir')

from master_call import master_call_interface as master_call
```

Importing `master_call` itself works perfectly fine, the issue is that inside off `master_call` I import `get_data.py`. I do this with the following code:

```
-- master_call.py

import sys
sys.path.append("../get_data_dir")

from get_data import get_data_module
```

When printing out `sys.path` I can see `../get_data_dir` inside of it but Python still isn't able to find the `get_data.py` file in `/get_data_dir`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

(there is an `__init__.py` file in every directory, I removed it here for readability)

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. The problem is while the directory of the `master_call.py` file is `/code/data_api/weather_data/master_call` the current working directory (CWD) is `/` since that is where `app.py` is located.

To fix it we simply fetch absolute file path in each python script with

`current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)).replace('\\', '/')`

and pre-pend it to any file path we're appending with `sys.path.append`

So it'd look like this in practice:

```
import sys
import os
current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)).replace('\\', '/')

sys.path.append(f'{current_path}./code/data_api/weather_data/master_call_dir')

from master_call import master_call_interface as master_call
```